# It is possible to create and save custom live photo in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

It is possible to create and save to camera roll a "Live Photo" created by a set of images provided by user?

Comment: [apple docs on live photos](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios//documentation/Photos/Reference/PHLivePhoto_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/PHLivePhoto/requestLivePhotoWithResourceFileURLs:placeholderImage:targetSize:contentMode:resultHandler:) This leaves it in the middle. You can create a Live Photo but only from Live Photo Data. So if you can recreate that data somehow: YES, else NO

Comment: really cool, in your opinion it is possible to use this CLI on a iOS project?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34108728/2227743