# Saving Already Created Live Photos

Tags: ios, swift, phlivephoto

I've got some live photos created JPEG and MOV files, now i want to import them into the app that would allow the user to save the live photos to their photo library. How can i go about doing this?

I've looked into this: https://github.com/genadyo/LivePhotoDemoSwift Which basically allows you to record video and turn it into a live photo.  But since i've already created the "live photos", can i save them to the camera roll right away or do i need to follow a different route?

Comment: You could use `PHLivePhoto.requestLivePhotoWithResourceFileURLs` to create a Live Photo from the JPEG and the MOV - then you would be able to save it to the library. Take example in my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33990830/working-with-live-photos-in-playground

Comment: Super useful comment Eric. I would say that solves it, add an answer if you wish and i'll accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a LivePhoto from separate elements from a LivePhoto by using `PHLivePhoto.requestLivePhotoWithResourceFileURLs`, you will then be able to save it to the library.

```
func makeLivePhotoFromItems(imageURL: NSURL, videoURL: NSURL, previewImage: UIImage, completion: (livePhoto: PHLivePhoto) -> Void) {
    PHLivePhoto.requestLivePhotoWithResourceFileURLs([imageURL, videoURL], placeholderImage: previewImage, targetSize: CGSizeZero, contentMode: PHImageContentMode.AspectFit) {
        (livePhoto, infoDict) -> Void in
        if let lp = livePhoto {
            completion(livePhoto: lp)
        }
    }
}

makeLivePhotoFromItems(imgURL, videoURL: movURL, previewImage: prevImg) { (livePhoto) -> Void in
    // "livePhoto" is your PHLivePhoto object, save it/use it here
}
```

You will need the JPEG file URL, the MOV file URL, and a "preview" image (which is usually just the JPEG or a lighter version of it).

Full example working in a Playground [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33990830/working-with-live-photos-in-playground).

Comment: Note: the full [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33990830/working-with-live-photos-in-playground) also has a Swift 3 version.

Comment: Could you please explain how to save a `PHLivePhoto` instance to photo library?