# Create PHLivePhoto Programmatically From UIImages

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, phlivephoto, apple-live-photos

How can you create a PHLivePhoto programmatically in Objective-C (such as from multiple UIImages, or some other means)? I can't find any solution in Apple's documentation. I know this must be possible in some way as there are multiple apps on the App Store that provide animated Live Photos to use as the Lock Screen on the iPhone 6S.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks

Comment: +1, I'm currently trying to do the same! Someone put some insight information together: https://www.reddit.com/r/iphone/comments/3n48qp/iphone_6s_how_to_create_a_custom_live_photo_from/ My idea atm: Create GIF from UIImages and convert it to a live photo. I'm stuck at the second step obviously. There must be a direct way for sure...

Comment: This Repo could be of interest too https://github.com/genadyo/LivePhotoDemo

Comment: I'm attempting to do a similar thing. I'm converting my images to a .mov file from this example [http://stackoverflow.com/a/30801061](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30801061). Then, I'm going to take that file and a placeholder .jpg image to create the Live Photo, as is done here [http://stackoverflow.com/a/35573516](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35573516). I'll let you know how it goes once I've finished coding it all out.