# How to create live wallpaper for iPhone?

Tags: ios, iphone, live-wallpaper

I want to develop live wallpaper app for iOS for 3d touch Apple devices. I tried with gif images and videos but somehow it did not worked. Is it possible? Am I in the wrong direction? [This](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/18610) tells its a video. But when I downloaded a live wallpaper from a app and checked its extension its jpeg. Can someone explain?

I will appreciate any help.

Comment: have you checked [this similar question](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/18610) or [iOS9 docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS9_1.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016572-DontLinkElementID_2)? Some other can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36729038/create-phlivephoto-programmatically-from-uiimages) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37001612/how-to-make-phlivephoto-from-mov-file)

Comment: Yes. But when I downloaded a live wallpaper from a app and checked its extension its jpeg. Not a video and link tells its a video

Comment: You have to create live photo and set it as wallpaper.